# AnyLogic - how to avoid fillSchedule error when the schedule is empty?

Tags: anylogic

I have a simulation model that contains several schedules for moving the trucks between origin and destination stations. The inputs are created automatically by a Python script and in some cases, one or two of the schedules can be empty -  meaning that I don't want the trucks move in those directions. An example is given below:

[image]

In such cases, the model throws the following error:

[image]

Is there a more elegant way of suppressing this error? (i.e. except giving a dummy row as input with all zeros)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that since the scehdules are dragged onto the canvas they get created automatically when the Main agent gets created and you have no control over them... you can't do `try() catch()` and you also can't prevent them from being created if their tables are empty... or just let them be created with a blank value...

You have two options:

Option 1:
So you need to create the schedules programmatically - using the trick described in [this article](https://www.theanylogicmodeler.com/post/how-to-programmatically-redraw-a-chart) - you can get to the code used to create the schedules.

```
 public Schedule<Integer> schedule = new Schedule<Integer>(
    this, true, SUNDAY, 7L * TIME_UNIT_DAY, TIME_UNIT_DAY, null, 0, _schedule_Starts_xjal(), null, _schedule_Values_xjal(), false, null, true, true );
```

and then the schedule gets populated using

```
if (schedule.isInitialized()) {
        new TableElementDatabaseBuilder(this).setSqlQuery("SELECT time, unit FROM truck_sc_ip").fillSchedule(
          schedule,
          Integer.class,
          true,
          true,
          604800000L,
          false,
          false,
          3600000L
          );
    }
```

You also need to create two variables for each schedule...

`Object[] _schedule_Values_xjal()` and `Object[]_schedule_Starts_xjal()`

There might be some other parts of the logic that gets created that I missed here but this should be sufficient.

Option 2:
The alternative is that you simply read in the entries into the DB and create your own Java class that you use as a schedule (my personal preference)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jaco-Ben! Seems like a great approach. Can you please help me with these two errors popping up after implementing this? `Description: The method _schedule_Values_xjal() is undefined for the type Main`, `Description: The method _schedule_Starts_xjal() is undefined for the type Main.`

Comment: See updated answer: Create two new obejcts for each schedule `Object[] _schedule_Values_xjal()` and `Object[]_schedule_Starts_xjal()`

Comment: Upvoting this answer; it helped me go in the correct direction. But this alone did not solve the issue. Especially it is not possible to declare the methods Object[]_schedule_Starts_xjal() manually.

Comment: Thank you. I see those names are reserved by AnyLogic, so just create your own variable names and use them in the constructor. I will update the answer later. Did you still go with option 1, or option 2? I would do option 2.

Comment: Thank you! I went with option 1, because could not understand well the second option. With option 1, although it works, I bumped into time zone issues, which gives me discomfort. I already have the data in the AnyLogic database..what exactly my class do? I want to use this schedule in a source block to create agents.

Comment: Option 2 would be to create your own Schedule object, but if you want to use it directly in a source then Option 1 is better. But I would still go for option 2 and use Dynamic events to inject agents into the source - then I have complete control over the creation of agents. Time Zones and especially daylight savings can be a big pain. I always set my models to some timezone that does not have daylight savings - else clients from other parts of the world get strange results for at least 2 days of the year.